# How to add multiple products to WooCommerce grouped product? Help for a small UK non-profit

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I help a UK non-profit which provides free educational health DVD lessons in multiple languages to disadvantaged communities throughout the world.
This is us!
https://tme.org.uk/dvds/
We have over 60 languages which the lessons are translated into.
Each language is setup as a Category.
Within each language there are up to 8 topics (sub categories) 
Each topic contains individual lessons (products)
Not all Languages have all the topics (sub categories) translated. So come sub categories are empty.
Currently if our beneficiaries need to order multiple 'lessons / products'  they have to add each one individually.
To explain what I mean:
Here is a category page for one of the languages
https://tme.org.uk/dvds/acholi/.
If you click on one of the topics (sub categories) 
Addiction
https://tme.org.uk/dvds/acholi/addiction-acholi/
It is impossible for someone to choose all the products and 'send them' to the basket.
They have to select each one and this not a realistic practice.

I am working on the idea of using Grouped Products
Where we create products which include all items.
1) A grouped product which includes all lessons/ products in the language (main category).
2) A grouped product which includes all lessons/ products in a topic (subcategory of the main language category)
I hope this makes some sense!
The issue I have is that with each grouped product I have to search and find each product individually.
Which is impossible.
What I need to find a way to do is to be able to select a group of products at one time and use them in the grouped product.
Something which is not available! 
Can anyone advise how to select multiple products to use in a Grouped Product? 
Or any other solution>
All help gratefully appreciated.

Andrew

Comment: I know this would probably be a significant undertaking, but would switching to a system that uses product variations be a better long-term solution? It would make creating grouped products probably easier.

Comment: Hi @TPaone
Thanks for the reply.
Strangely enough I was just looking at Product Variations just now.
Will explore and comment back here.